# LaserScan msg ranges.resize() - Arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am getting the following error when compiling my rosserial_arduino code for sampling and sending a LaserScan msg.

This code works just fine in a standard ros c++ node. Does this member not exist? Am I not accessing it correctly?
Thanks!

**Compilation Error:**

*error: request for member ‘resize’ in ‘scan_msg.sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ranges’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’*

**Code in Question:**

`unsigned int node_count = 10;
scan_msg.ranges.resize(node_count);`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188515/laserscan-msg-ranges.resize()---arduino/) by [Kent Williams](https://answers.ros.org/users/1646/kent-williams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that using rosserial_arduino, the ranges are not represented by a std::vector (as in roscpp) but by a float* (saving space on a embedded system, probably mainly by not pulling in std::vector). A float pointer naturally does not provide any of the member functions a std::vector does.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kent Williams](https://answers.ros.org/users/1646/kent-williams/) on 2014-08-01**:
Thanks for the response Stefan!

So if the vector is of type float*, should I be declaring and initializing my ranges variable like so:

float *ranges = new float[num_readings];

and then assigning the ranges to the msg type like so:

scan_msg.ranges = ranges;

This seems to be restricting the ros serial python node from connecting.... so something is off.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-08-01**:
Memory is pretty restricted on Arduino, it could be that you exceed the processor´s memory if you allocate a too large array. See also http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations for an explanation how things work.